# NASM assembler floating point exception

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The program should check if the remainder of one of the elements of the array after dividing by 3 is 1 and if it is it should add the element to the final sum.

```
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_EXIT equ 1
STDOUT equ 1

segment .data
x: db 3
   db 2
   db 1
   db 3
   db 5
y db 3

segment .bss
res resb 1

segment .text
    global _start

_start:
mov ecx,5 ; number of iterations
xor ebx,ebx ; ebx the sum
mov edx,x ; addres of the first element 
xor eax,eax ;in eax will be the number of elements that are satisfying the conditions i wrote in the text             ;above   

petlja:
push ecx
push edx
push eax
push ebx
mov cl,[y] ; storing 3 in lower 8 bits of cx register
mov ax, [edx]; storing element of array in ax
div cl
cmp ah,1
jnz izlaz
pop ebx
pop eax
pop edx
add ebx,[edx] ;adding to the final sum and increasing the number of elements
inc eax
push edx
push eax
push ebx
izlaz:
pop ebx
pop eax
pop edx
pop ecx
inc edx ; increasing the address
loop petlja

add ebx,'0'; adding character '0' for printing
mov [res],ebx; moving final sum to mem. loc. res
mov eax,SYS_WRITE ; system call for write
mov ebx,STDOUT
mov ecx, res
mov edx, 1
int 80h ; kernel call

mov eax, SYS_EXIT
int 80h ; kernel call
```

I tried some solutions form this forum and nothing works. I tried partial coding of divison by 3 and checking the remainder and it worked perfectly fine. But when i try with the loop it simply wont work.

Comment: Check your load sizes. You can use `movzx/movsx` to load smaller data into a wider register. For example, `mov ax, [edx]` will load two elements at a time and `0x503 / 3` can't fit in a byte. Also, you can avoid most of those `push/pop` by choosing different registers to hold the state.

Comment: Thank you,@MargaretBloom, I couldn't find any of the movzx/movsx commands in the https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm, the documentation that I was using... Although I would like to avoid this stack mess, I am limited to using only these 4. Thanks for the advice, though! Since the program works perfectly fine now should you post it as an answer?

Comment: That tutorial is not good, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm uses 4-byte (dword) loads for an array of 1-byte data elements, and even stores 3 bytes past the end of the `sum: db 0` with `mov  [sum], ebx`.  Look at an instruction-set reference, compiler output, or a tutorial from someone that knows what they're doing.  (Or hasn't over-simplified to the point of being wrong if "keeping it simple for beginners" is their excuse.)  Their example for working with multi-digit numbers also uses BCD decimal digits instead of converting to binary and back!

Comment: See links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for ISA references (like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) and guides / tutorials / documentation.